# SonarQube not starting anymore after upgrade to 5.1

Tags: sonarqube

I upgraded Sonarqube using the Ubuntu update mechanism. I have now version 5.1.2:

```
$ dpkg -s sonar | grep Version
Version: 5.1.2
```

Unfortunately, it does not start up. I have updated all my plugins in the `extensions/plugins` folder:

```
$ ls -l
total 16388
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root        128 Feb 21  2015 README.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonar nogroup 2404852 May  6 15:01 sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonar nogroup 7080268 Sep  1 16:44 sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonar nogroup 2965677 Aug 25 16:12 sonar-java-plugin-3.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonar nogroup   30646 Oct 22  2014 sonar-ldap-plugin-1.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonar nogroup 4281231 May  7 10:48 sonar-pmd-plugin-2.4.1.jar
```

You can view the contents of the log file here: http://pastebin.com/4i5UPaP4

Comment: your ES index seem to be corrupted. Stop SQ, delete directory es in SQ's data directory and restart SQ. ES index will be rebuilt from scratch (which can take a long time depending on your data) and it should work again. Can't tell why it got corrupted without sonar.log of the migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error in the log file you provide, your ES index seem to be corrupted.

Stop SQ, delete directory `es` in SQ's `data` directory and restart SQ.
ES index will be rebuilt from scratch (which can take a long time depending on your data) and it should work again.

There is no way telling why and how the index got corrupted without the `sonar.log` of the migration and detailed information on the setup and how the migration was performed.